# SQL query creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do a query without using views that displays the automobile brand that has the maximum number of cars that have a single owner.

that's the table that I have

```
CAR(idcar, brand, name, year_p)
OWNER(idowner,name, b_date)
PROPERTY(idcar,idowner,date_b, date_s)
```

That's what I was writing..

```
SELECT Car.brand, COUNT(PROPERTY.idowner) as con
FROM PROPERTY JOIN CAR ON Car.idcar=Property.idcar
GROUP BY Car.brand
ORDER BY con ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

It's ok? what I can do to improve it?

That's how it should work

```
       CAR
-----------------
1|FIAT|test1|2000
2|Alfa|test2|2011
3|FIAT|test3|2001
4|Alfa|test4|2006
5|Alfa|test5|2004

   OWNER
-----------
1|John|1990
2|Jack|1980
3|Sam |1991
4|Rick|1980
5|Cris|1993
6|Holm|1992


  PROPERTY
-------------
1|1|2000|2000
2|1|2001|2003
3|2|2000|2004
1|3|2002|2005
4|4|2004|2006
5|6|2003|2008
2|5|2001|2009
```

So the query should return Alfa because I've 3 people that have only one car and those 3 people have one alfa ( so 3 alfa). It can't be FIAT because I only have 2 people with only one car that is a FIAT(so 2 FIAT). The OWNER n1 is excluded because he has 2 car

Comment: Don't use the word 'coc' in your code.

Comment: @ragerory And that matters because...?

Comment: @ragerory 'coc' isn't an SQL keyword

Comment: This question would probably be better for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow, as it is asking for improvements to working code.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I am aware it is not a SQL keyword. But read it. It sounds dirty.

Comment: Now should be less "dirty"..

Comment: @ragerory And that affects the functioning or maintainability of the code how…?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 code readability and meaningful names don't mean anything to you? Looks like you got a little fired up about that comment. Light humor never hurt anyone, bud.

Comment: @ragerory `coc` (count of cars) is a lot more meaningful than `con`, and is less verbose than using full words like `countOfCars`.

Comment: saucer of milk, party of one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right path with your query, it's only need a little modification...

First if you want to select brand with most owner than you should order them in descending order so the max will be at the top... And second you need to add WHERE clause which will exclude all owner that have more then one car...

It should look like this:

```
SELECT c.brand, COUNT(p.idowner) as con
FROM PROPERTY p
JOIN CAR c
ON c.idcar=p.idcar
WHERE p.idowner NOT IN (SELECT idowner
                        FROM (SELECT idowner, COUNT(idowner) as c
                              FROM PROPERTY
                              GROUP BY idowner) x
                        WHERE c > 1)
GROUP BY c.brand
ORDER BY con DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c149/18) to take a look how it's work...

GL!

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your query is not correct.  It returns the brands that have the most properties for its cars.  That may or may not have to do with the number of owners.  I'm sure there's a relationship of some sort ("no properties" --> "no owners" and vice versa).

In any case, I don't know what you mean by "the maximum number of cars that have a single owner".  You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle would also be helpful.

Comment: Edited.. I hope that the problem is more understandable now

Answer (score 0):

```html
--CTE to Get single owner
WITH CTEsingleowner(ct, idowner) 
     AS (SELECT Count(1) AS ct, 
                idowner 
         FROM   property  WITH(nolock) 
         GROUP  BY idowner 
         HAVING Count(1) = 1) 


-- Select brand with maximum number of single owner
-- with ties is used to resolve confilict  more than one record set returned 

SELECT TOP (1) WITH ties Count(1) AS cnt, 
                         brand 
FROM   CTEsingleowner ct 
       JOIN property p WITH(nolock) 
         ON p.idowner = ct.idowner 
       JOIN car c WITH(nolock) 
         ON ( c.idcar = p.idcar ) 
GROUP  BY brand 
ORDER  BY cnt DESC ;
```

--CTE to Get single owner

WITH CTEsingleowner(ct, idowner)
AS (SELECT Count(1) AS ct,idowner 
FROM   property  WITH(nolock) 
GROUP  BY idowner 
HAVING Count(1) = 1)

-- Select brand with maximum number of single owner
-- with ties is used to resolve conflict  more than one rows returned

SELECT TOP (1) WITH ties Count(1) AS cnt, brand 
FROM   CTEsingleowner ct 
JOIN property p WITH(nolock) 
ON p.idowner = ct.idowner 
JOIN car c WITH(nolock) 
ON ( c.idcar = p.idcar ) 
GROUP  BY brand
ORDER  BY cnt DESC ;

Comment: Could you add some words to explain your answer please?

Comment: yes .. Sure 1) We Create a CTE that Select Car Owner from property tabel who have on one car. 2)  Grouped CTE with car  and   property  table  on the basis of brand  this will give count of brand having single owner 3) Use With ties to  return all  brand that have  maximum single owner if more than one exist . in above case only one alpha is exist